# missing outlook 2010 add-in template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am currently trying to build an Add-in for Outlook 2010. I am following the instructions under

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/07/12/building-and-deploying-an-outlook-2010-add-in-part-1-of-2.aspx

Sadly I am stopped pretty much right away when I try to open up the "Outlook 2010 Add-in" Template in Visual Studio 2010 Premium. The "Outlook 2010 Add-in" Template is missing, as are all Office related Templates. There should be an Office Node containing all the Office related Templates in the "New Project" Window. This node is missing.

What is the problem?

Ps: it is missing for all programming languages.